# HTTP/1.0 response to HTTP/1.1 request

Tags: http

Is it alright to respond with HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 request?

I am implementing HTTP communication through simple sockets and clients make requests with both HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 but protocol is independent of HTTP version so I want to always respond with HTTP/1.0 to all requests.
Does HTTP standard bear such communication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it's alright. Otherwise, if you only supported HTTP/1.0, what could you do?

If HTTP 1.2 came out today, what do you think all existing HTTP 1.1 servers would send as replies to HTTP 1.2 queries? Of course, it'll have to be HTTP 1.1 replies -- that's all they know how to do.

Just make sure you don't follow HTTP 1.1 rules where they differ. For example, keep alives are *not* enabled by default. If a client sees an HTTP 1.0 reply, it will assume HTTP 1.0 semantics.

Comment: "Keep-aliving" is precisely I want to avoid when started to migrate to HTTP/1.0 to handle ALL existing clients. Well, I hope it is all so :)

Comment: So just send `Connection: close` headers in your response to `HTTP/1.1` requests. (You can include them in responses to `HTTP/1.0` requests to, but there's no need.) However, then you'll still have to make sure to reply to `HTTP/1.0` queries with `HTTP/1.0` replies. It's probably easiest to just forget about 1.1 entirely.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, is Http 1.0 allowed to reply upon a change in the major version? e.g. Should Http 1.0 do error when the request is HTTP/2.0 ?

Comment: @Pacerier: If the major version is different, you shouldn't assume you can understand the request at all. So the right response is to return a [505](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error). (You can also return a 505 to an HTTP/1.2 query if you want. Just make sure to change things promptly if HTTP/1.2 is ever released. That would be a bad choice for an embedded device.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I mean is this behavior RFCed?

Comment: Yes, RFC 1616, section 10.5.6, "The server is indicating that it is unable or unwilling to complete the request using the same *major* version as the client ...".